# multiprocessing pool vs thredpool executor in python

Tags: python, multithreading, pool, threadpoolexecutor

I am running into an error when using multithreading, which I don't see when I use multiprocessing.

Say for an example,
When I use :

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
p=Pool(156)
p.map(job,arg)
```

Only 156 jobs run at any time.

While when I use:

```
with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=156) as executor:
      for job in jobs:
          future = executor.submit(job,arg)
```

New, threads keep getting created even if existing jobs are not yet finished.

How to avoid threads running over, and keep thread pool in check?

Comment: Your syntax isn't correct. Looks like you're missing a `for` and also, do you have 156 CPUs at your disposal?

Comment: I have added for.